# how to update a dialog from another dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I have a jquery dialog and inside that dialog an option to edit a field and that option shows another dialog for editing, what I want is that when I edit the second dialog it updates my first dialog, but the dialogs are in different files.

Dialog 1:

```
$("#dialogComponentes").html(obj.form).dialog({

    title: obj.titulo,
    width: dWidth,
    height: dHeight,
    modal: true,
    position: {
        my: "center",
        at: "center",
        of: $("#dvDialogUbicacionElementos")
    },
    buttons: [{
           id: 'btnGrabar',
           text: 'Grabar',
           click: function() {
                grabarComponentes();                
           }
    },
    {
            id: 'btnCancelar',
            text: 'Cancelar',
            click: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            idComponente = -1;
            }
        }
    ],
     close: function() {
         $(this).dialog("close");
        idComponente = -1;
    },
         dialogClass: "overflow-fix"
});
```

dialog 2:

```
$("#dvDialogEdicionArchivo").html(obj.formulario).dialog({

                    title: "Editar archivo",
                    width: 400,
                    height: 200,
                    modal: true,
                    position: {
                        my: "center",
                        at: "center",
                        of: $("#dvDialogUbicacionElementos"),
                    },
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            text: "Grabar",
                            id: "btnEdicionArchivo",
                            click: function () {
                                edicionArchivoAdjunto();
                            },
                        },
                        {
                            text: "Cancelar",
                            id: "btnCancelarArchivo",
                            click: function () {
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                });
```